# How to convert values of array to array filtered

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I have this problem, I use Angular 8, I hope you can help me, I have been unable to solve it for a long time.

I have this array:

```
datos = [{
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'ADMON',
    Value: '1'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'ADMON',
    Value: '2'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'ADMON',
    Value: '3'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'USER',
    Value: '1'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'USER',
    Value: '2'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'USER',
    Value: '4'
  },
]
```

I need to filter and group them like this :

```
result = [
  {ADMON: {0: 1, 
           1: 2, 
           2: 3, 
           3: 4}},
  {USER:  {0: 1, 
           1: 2, 
           2: 4}}
];
```

I've tried many ways but I can't, I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think the result can be `result = [
  {ADMON: {0: 1, 
           1: 2, 
           2: 3, 
  {USER:  {0: 1, 
           1: 2, 
           2: 4}}
];`  Because the ADMIN don't have value as 4 "3: 4" , Please check it.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried - your best attempt.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I thank you too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one potential solutions that use a number of array methods to accomplish the task at hand.

```js
const datos = [{
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'ADMON',
    Value: '1'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'ADMON',
    Value: '2'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'ADMON',
    Value: '3'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'USER',
    Value: '1'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'USER',
    Value: '2'
  },
  {
    Description: 'Puede Insertar',
    Id: 1,
    Type: 'USER',
    Value: '4'
  }
];

const grouped = datos.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc[el.Type]) acc[el.Type] = {};
  const index = Object.values(acc[el.Type]).length;
  acc[el.Type] = {
    ...acc[el.Type],
    [index]: el.Value
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const final = Object.entries(grouped).map(([key, val]) => {
  return { [key]: val }
});

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

**Some time ago I found this function and use many time:**

```
let groupBy = function (xs, key) {
 return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
 }, {});
};
```

**If you try in your scenarios:**

```js
    let groupBy = function (xs, key) {
     return xs.reduce(function (rv, x) {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
        return rv;
     }, {});
    };


    let datos = [{
      Description: 'Puede Insertar',
      Id: 1,
      Type: 'ADMON',
      Value: '1'
    },
      {
        Description: 'Puede Insertar',
        Id: 1,
        Type: 'ADMON',
        Value: '2'
      },
      {
        Description: 'Puede Insertar',
        Id: 1,
        Type: 'ADMON',
        Value: '3'
      },
      {
        Description: 'Puede Insertar',
        Id: 1,
        Type: 'USER',
        Value: '1'
      },
      {
        Description: 'Puede Insertar',
        Id: 1,
        Type: 'USER',
        Value: '2'
      },
      {
        Description: 'Puede Insertar',
        Id: 1,
        Type: 'USER',
        Value: '4'
      },
    ]
    
    console.log(groupBy(datos, 'Type'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me, I have a lot to learn, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

```js
const datos = [{Description:'Puede Insertar',Id:1,Type:'ADMON',Value:'1'},{Description:'Puede Insertar',Id:1,Type:'ADMON',Value:'2'},{Description:'Puede Insertar',Id:1,Type:'ADMON',Value:'3'},{Description:'Puede Insertar',Id:1,Type:'USER',Value:'1'},{Description:'Puede Insertar',Id:1,Type:'USER',Value:'2'},{Description:'Puede Insertar',Id:1,Type:'USER',Value:'4'}];


let result = Object.entries(datos.reduce((acc, {Type, Value}) => {
          (acc[Type] = acc[Type] || []).push(Value);
            return acc;
               }, {}))
             .map((o) => { return {[o[0]]: {...o[1]}}});
 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I didn't do it, I can't give you points, I don't have the points yet. I'm very grateful with you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would probably do it:

```
// First pass reduce to a map of your index / value maps keyed by type.
// Grouping tends to be easier in a map than an array.
const groupByType = datos.reduce((result, d, i) => {
  result[d.Type] = result[d.Type] || {};
  result[d.Type][i] = d.Value;
  return result;
}, {} as Record<string, Record<string, string>>);

// Once we have a map, we can convert it to the final array
const arrayResult = Object.keys(groupByType).map(t => {
  return {
    [t]: groupByType[t]
  };
});
```

Worth mentioning that I intentionally did not use the spread syntax inside of the reduce callback. In many cases it's probably fine to do so, but if your dataset is large enough, there can be a performance impact since you'd be creating + copying on every iteration. Since creating the object and setting its properties is completely encapsulated in the reduce function, there shouldn't be any concerns with mutating vs other cases where immutability might be a concern.